# Access to specific items with glide.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using glide.js and i'd appreciate some ideas to get this working.

I need to connect (items < slider 1 < page 1) to (items < slider 2 < page 2). The subject: (e.g.) If i click on **2nd item** from the 1st page, then the 2nd page is shown and the **2nd item** from the 2nd page is also shown. Here's some code:

## Page 1

```js
// Glide Page 1

var glide = $('.slider').glide().data('api_glide');

$(window).on('keyup', function(key) {
  if (key.keyCode === 13) {
    glide.jump(3, console.log('Wooo!'));
  };
});

$('.slider__arrows-item').on('click', function() {
  console.log(glide.current());
});
```

```html
<!-- Page 1 -->

<link href="http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/css/glide.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/js/jquery.glide.min.js"></script>

<body bgcolor="#999">

<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slider__wrapper">
    <li class="slider__item">
      <a class="button" href="http://www.example.com/Page_2.php" id="#content_01">Access to Content 1 on Page 2</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="slider__item ">
      <a class="button " href="http://www.example.com/Page_2.php" id="#content_02">Access to Content 2 on Page 2</a> 
    </li>
    <li class="slider__item ">
      <a class="button" href="http://www.example.com/Page_2.php" id="#content_03">Access to Content 3 on Page 2</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## Page 2

```js
// Glide Page 2

var glide = $('.slider').glide().data('api_glide');

$(window).on('keyup', function(key) {
  if (key.keyCode === 13) {
    glide.jump(3, console.log('Wooo!'));
  };
});

$('.slider__arrows-item').on('click', function() {
  console.log(glide.current());
});
```

```html
<!-- Page 2 -->

<link href="http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/css/glide.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/js/jquery.glide.min.js"></script>

<body bgcolor="#000">

<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slider__wrapper">
    <li class="slider__item" id=“#content_01”>
      <div>Some Content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="slider__item" id=“#content_02”>
      <div>Some Content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="slider__item" id=“#content_03”>
      <div>Some Content</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "Connect"?

Comment: Sorry about my poor english. I mean link.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do this:http://www.crumlinroadgaol.com/slider.html - can you upload what you have to somewhere that can be viewed, e.g. jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm trying but anyways i'd uploading something is not working, that's why i need some help.

Comment: crumlinroadgaol.com/slider.html is not what i need because the content linked to the buttons inside the slider is not containing another slider. I'd like to get this: if you click the first button on slide 1 on page 1, then the second page is loaded and the first slide is shown. If you click the second button on the slide 2 on the first page, the the second page is loaded and the second slide is shown. And so on...